# BibLaTeX: Combine same author, different years into one citation

Tags: biblatex

In the MWE below, `\citet{macdonald2015, macdonald2016}` becomes "MacDonald (2015) and MacDonald (2016)". `\citep{macdonald2015, macdonald2016}` becomes "(MacDonald, 2015; MacDonald 2016)". How do I make it print "MacDonald (2015, 2016)" and "(MacDonald, 2015; 2016)?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,natbib=true,backend=biber,sorting=nyt,mincitenames=1,maxcitenames=2,url=false,giveninits=true,uniquename=false,maxbibnames=100,uniquelist=false,dashed=false]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{macdonald2015,
  title = {On Having a Farm},
  volume = {42},
  journaltitle = {Journal of Science and Stuff},
  author = {MacDonald, O.},
  date = {2015}
}
@article{macdonald2016,
  title = {Noise reduction in livestock},
  volume = {43},
  journaltitle = {Journal of Science and Stuff},
  author = {MacDonald, O.},
  date = {2016}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\title{A document}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
In this text I cite \citet{macdonald2015, macdonald2016} for the mwe. 
And now i cite the same clever fellow \citep{macdonald2015, macdonald2016} again.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer: Change style to `authoryear-comp`.

`\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,…]{biblatex}`

Comment: \usepackage[% style=authoryear-comp, backend=biber, maxcitenames=2, giveninits, citestyle=authoryear ]{biblatex}, is not working

Comment: Does this have any other side-effects?